# Why is the initial state of my inputs ignored?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Please check out my fiddle below. A checkbox with nested checkboxes. The change function works fine: if any `$('#checkbox' + x)` is checked, the corresponding `$('.entry' + x)` shows, and if unchecked, hidden.

The initial state of my checkboxes is ignored until at least one of the checkboxes are clicked. In the example, initially all `$('.entry' + x)` show, although #checkbox1, -2 and -3 are initially checked. But: if I then uncheck #checkbox2, only .entry1 and .entry3 show, all other elements hide. From there on, everything works as expected.

I've tried the following:

1. `$('#checkbox1').click();` so just clicking without "actually" clicking (leads to checkbox1 being unchecked but nothing else happens until I click on any of the checkboxes)
2. setting a checkbox to `.prop('checked', true)` (pretty much the same result like in 1)
3. I've also tried it with an if/else statement like

`

```
if ($('#checkbox' + x).prop('checked') == 'true') {
$('.entry' + x).show();
}
else{
$('.entry' + x).hide();
}`
```

Still nothing. How do I gain control over the initial states of the checkboxes in this example? Please help me, I just can't figure it out. Just to make clear what i want to achieve: I'd like to be able to set the props to checked and have the checked/unchecked "+ x" elements be hidden and shown accordingly, and create .on('click', ...) events to change the props later on and have them always behave accordingly.

```js
 $(function () {
              // CHECKBOXES GROU AND NESTED CHECKBOXES HIDE/SHOW SYNCHRONIZING
              $.fn.nestedCheckboxes = function (stopPropogation) {
                this.addClass('nestedCheckboxes');
                this.on('click', ':has( > input[type=checkbox])', nestedCheckboxHandler);
                function nestedCheckboxHandler(evt) {
                  if ($(evt.target).is("input[type=checkbox]")) {
                    var parentContainer = $(this);
                    var checkbox = parentContainer
                      .find(' > input[type=checkbox]:eq(0)');
                    var parentCheckbox = parentContainer
                      .parent()
                      .closest(':has( > input[type=checkbox])')
                      .children('input[type=checkbox]');
        
                    if (evt.target == checkbox[0]) {
                      $('input[type=checkbox]', parentContainer)
                        .prop("checked", checkbox.prop("checked"));
                      $(function () {
                        $(new Array(5).fill(1).map((_, i) => i + 1)).each(function (idx, x) { // Array for the number of div elements
                          $('.entry' + x)[($('#checkbox' + x).prop("checked") ? "show" : "hide")](); // synchronize
        
                          $('#checkbox' + x).on('change', function () {      // toggle on change     
                            $('.entry' + x).toggle();
                          });
                        });
                      });
                    }
                    var parentCheckboxValue = !parentCheckbox
                      .parent()
                      .find("input[type=checkbox]")
                      .not(parentCheckbox[0])
                      .is("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)");
        
                    parentCheckbox.prop("checked", parentCheckboxValue);
                  } else if (stopPropogation) {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                  }
                };
              };
                $('.treeX-container form').nestedCheckboxes();
            });
```

```css
* {
            list-style-type:none;
            }
            .l0{
            color: #000;
            font-weight: bold;
            }
            .entry1,
            .l1{
            color: #ff3333;
            }
            .entry2,
            .l2{
            color: #003DFF;
            }
            .entry3,
            .l3{
            color: #FF8A0E
            }
            .entry4,
            .l4{
            color: #45F300;
            }
            .entry5,
            .l5{
            color: #E700EF;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <div class="treeX-container">
              <ul>
                <form>
                  <li>
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                      <span class="l0">ALL</span>
                        <ul>
                          <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" checked />
                           <label class="l1">Entry1</label>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="1" checked />
                            <label class="l2">Entry2</label>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="1" checked />
                            <label class="l3">Entry3</label>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="1" />
                            <label class="l4">Entry4</label>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" value="1" />
                            <label class="l5">Entry5</label>
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                   </li>
                </form>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            <div class="entry1">ENTRY1</div>
            <div class="entry2">ENTRY2</div>
            <div class="entry3">ENTRY3</div>
            <div class="entry4">ENTRY4</div>
            <div class="entry5">ENTRY5</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: What do you expect this line: `$(this).nestedCheckboxHandler;` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly simplified approach. `showHideEntries()` is a utility function that runs a loop over all checkboxes and sets the visibility of the associated entries below. It is called initially in the jQuery onload routine and later on whenever a checkbox is clicked.

`$cb` is a jQuery object that references all the "normal" (single) checkboxes.

```js
$(function() {
  const $cb = $(".treeX-container")
    .on("click", "input", function() {
      if (!this.id)
        $cb.prop("checked", this.checked);
      showHideEntries();
    }).find("ul ul input");

  function showHideEntries() {
    $cb.each(function() {
      $("." + this.id.replace("checkbox", "entry")).toggle(this.checked)
    })
  }
  showHideEntries();
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.l0 {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.entry1,
.l1 {
  color: #ff3333;
}

.entry2,
.l2 {
  color: #003DFF;
}

.entry3,
.l3 {
  color: #FF8A0E
}

.entry4,
.l4 {
  color: #45F300;
}

.entry5,
.l5 {
  color: #E700EF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="treeX-container">
  <ul>
    <form>
      <li>
        <label class="l0"><input type="checkbox"/>
                      ALL</label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" checked />
            <label class="l1" for="checkbox1">Entry1</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="1" checked />
            <label class="l2" for="checkbox2">Entry2</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="1" checked />
            <label class="l3" for="checkbox3">Entry3</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="1" />
            <label class="l4" for="checkbox4">Entry4</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" value="1" />
            <label class="l5" for="checkbox5">Entry5</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="entry1">ENTRY1</div>
  <div class="entry2">ENTRY2</div>
  <div class="entry3">ENTRY3</div>
  <div class="entry4">ENTRY4</div>
  <div class="entry5">ENTRY5</div>
</div>
```

Here is another answer to the extended question, as posted in your comment below (building on V2 of your JSfiddle):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".treeX-container")
    .on("click", "input", function() {
      var $cb;
      if (!this.id){       // a group checkbox was clicked
        $cb=$("ul:first input",this.closest("li")); // get all subordinate checkboxes
        $cb.prop("checked",this.checked);           // and set them accordingly
      } else $cb=$(this);  // an individual checkbox option was clicked
      showHideEntries($cb);// update visibility of associated entry elements 
    });
  function showHideEntries($cb) {
    $cb.each(function() {
     if (this.id) $("." + this.id.replace("checkbox", "entry")).toggle(this.checked) 
    });
  }
  showHideEntries($("input"));
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.l0 {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.container {}

.item {
  background-color: #999999;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="treeX-container">
  <ul>
    <form>
      <li>
        <label class="l0"><input type="checkbox" />
        ALL</label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="1" checked />
            Entry1</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="1" checked />
            Entry2</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="1" checked />
            Entry3</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label class="l0"><input type="checkbox" />
            CheckboxGroup</label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" value="1" checked />
                Entry4</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox5" value="1" checked />
                Entry5</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox6" value="1" checked />
                Entry6</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox7" value="1" />
                Entry7</label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label class="l0"><input type="checkbox" />
                CheckboxGroup</label>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox8" value="1" checked />
                    Entry8</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox9" value="1" checked />
                    Entry9</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox10" value="1" checked />
                    Entry10</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox11" value="1" />
                    Entry11</label>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox12" value="1" />
                    Entry12</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
                <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox13" value="1" />
                Entry13</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox14" value="1" />
            Entry14</label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox15" value="1" />
            Entry15</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </form>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item entry1">1</div>
  <div class="item entry2">2</div>
  <div class="item entry3">3</div>
  <div class="item entry4">4</div>
  <div class="item entry5">5</div>
  <div class="item entry6">6</div>
  <div class="item entry7">7</div>
  <div class="item entry8">8</div>
  <div class="item entry9">9</div>
  <div class="item entry10">10</div>
  <div class="item entry11">11</div>
  <div class="item entry12">12</div>
  <div class="item entry13">13</div>
  <div class="item entry14">14</div>
  <div class="item entry15">15</div>
</div>
```

I had to rearrange the logic a little bit to deal with the different sets of checkboxes it needs to collect. Center part is now the expression `$cb=$("ul:first input",this.closest("li"));` that collects all the checkboxes of the "next ul" in case one of the "collection" checkboxes was clicked. `this.closest("li")` (a Vanilla-JS expression!!!!) moves up to the closest `li` element and from there on the jQuery selector `"ul:first input"` will find all input elements below the first `ul` element it encounters.

I also changed your `label`s such that they always surround the associated checkbox. This way you can click on a label text to activate the checkbox inside the label.

Comment: Carsten, thank you so much for this! In my code, this also works for deeper nested checkboxes, too. I've created two fiddles, V1 with my code, V2 with yours. Can you make your approach work for this scenario too? V1: https://jsfiddle.net/stst2022/8xv270ro/ V2: https://jsfiddle.net/stst2022/8g3wj5sh/3/

Comment: Ich seh gerade Du kommst aus Hannover, Grüße aus Mainz! Du würdest mir sehr helfen!! Hänge schon sehr lange an dem Problem und meine Versuche sind immer gescheitert.

Comment: Ich schaue es mir später an ;-). Bin gerade offline.

Comment: Super, danke! Ich find deinen Ansatz so cool weil ich dann bei den Checkboxen nicht mehr mit Arrays arbeiten muss, ich hab mehrere von diesen Checkboxlisten, alle unterschiedlicher Länge... und es wäre echt angenehm da ne einheitliche Lösung zu haben die für alle Checkboxlisten funktioniert :)

Comment: Hey @stst, please check again: I adjusted my script to suit your second jsfiddle example. "Das sollte jetzt passen!" ;-)

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you so much for this! I will look at your code now and I'm sure I'll learn a lot from it. Thank you!